# How do I pass different variables through an onclick function?

Tags: javascript, html

What I was doing is this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#deleteMe", function (){

    var id = $(this).data("id");
    console.log(id);

    // function to delete event by id goes here
});
```

My delete HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="deleteMe" data-id="">Delete</div>
```

A data-id value is given through a different function so that once the page has many events, the data-id field above has numbers like 90, 91, 92, etc. when the modal loads. So, for example:

```
<div id="deleteMe" data-id="90">Delete</div>
<div id="deleteMe" data-id="91">Delete</div>
<div id="deleteMe" data-id="92">Delete</div>
```

This works perfectly on the first time that I click 'Delete' - the event is deleted from the database like I want it to. Unfortunately every time I click a DIFFERENT event and click 'delete' again, the delete fails and the console.log says it was trying to delete the previous id of the FIRST element I deleted.

It's like the first time I use the onclick function it binds the original id I used, and every click from then on out keeps the same id instead of passing the new data-id. How do I work around this?

Ex.

Just clicked event 90, hit delete. Event deleted successfully! (Console.log = "Just tried to delete ID #90")
Just clicked event 91, hit delete. Nothing happens. (Console.log = "Just tried to delete ID #90"

On inspecting the elements before clicking delete, the correct data-ids are there - it's just on clicking 'delete' that it doesn't grab the new data-id value from the next event I'm trying to delete.

Comment: Might have something to do with them all having the same id.  use a class instead to identify the common elements -  `<div class="deleteMe" data-id="90">Delete</div>`

Comment: Just tried changing it to class and there's no difference - although I do remember somebody telling me that ids were supposed to be unique on the page, so I'll be doing that from now on. Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem, though!

Comment: Did you change your selector as well? `$(document).on("click", ".deleteMe", function (){`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HMXZf/

Comment: Yep, changed the selector too. I changed my function to look exactly like yours in the jsfiddle, but it's still trying to delete the old id, almost as if once the old id was assigned to that variable it doesn't want to reassign the new value to the same variable. It keeps saying its value is the value of the first deleted element no matter what data id I pass in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starter's, if you're going to have multiple elements labeled as `deleteMe` you should use a class rather than id. ID's should be unique. Perhaps the values you have for `data-id` should be the id's.

Assuming you changed the elements to:

```
<div class="deleteMe" data-id="90">Delete</div>
```

To delete the element that was clicked you could do this:

```
$('.deleteMe').click(function() {
  console.log('Deleting ID:', $(this).attr('data-id'));
  $(this).remove();
});
```

--EDIT--

Since folks mentioned that I missed the point of event delegation, you could do it this way to ensure that all future elements created with class `deleteMe` also respond to the click event:

```
$(document).on('click', '.deleteMe', function() {
  console.log('Deleting ID:', $(this).attr('data-id'));
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Why would they want to delete them all on document click?  .click() and document.on with a selector should be the same result here.

Comment: I just wasn't sure what he was going for because his example used `$(document).on('click', etc.)`

Comment: @jshanley that's event delegation : https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handlereventObject

Comment: Okay, then post him an answer using event delegation instead of just saying that this answer is wrong.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon edited to reflect your suggestion, now that I've read the docs you linked, I get your point.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this by changing this function:

```
var id = $(this).data("id");
```

to:

```
var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
```

I didn't think there was a difference, but double and triple-checking it confirms that these two functions operate differently.

Found some interesting information on it regarding DOM here: http://www.peterbe.com/plog/data-and-attr-in-jquery

Comment: That was exactly what I suggested doing ;) thanks for the link though, good info.

Comment: Oh I didn't see your edits! I see it now - thank you!